# ping xyz.com is not working but ping www.xyz.com is working

Tags: ping

Some one please help me in this

when I do ping xyz.com it is showing as host not reachable...

funky@li300-250:/etc/apache2$ ping xyz.com
ping: unknown host xyz.com
funky@li300-250:/etc/apache2$

Comment: This is most likely because DNS is not properly configured. I predict the question will be moved to Serverfault within the hour.

Comment: you could try to ping the IP ADDRESS IE. ping 192.168.1.254 "standard IP"

Answer (score 2):

Actually xyz.com can be not the same host as www.xyz.com and it can deny ICMP requests